# Show most viewed entries that have been added in the last 7 days

Tags: mysql

I want to show the most viewed entries that have been added in the last 7 days.

I've tried:

```
SELECT active, date_created, comments, views, URL, title, category, image1
FROM `tbl_news` 
WHERE DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) <= `date_created` 
ORDER BY `views` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

But with no success.

The date is in the standard format: 1310824884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The date is in the standard format: 1310824884

That is not mySQL's standard date format. If it's stored as a time stamp, use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to make it a proper mySQL date to compare against.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
SELECT active, date_created, comments, views, URL, title, category, image1
FROM `tbl_news`
WHere DATE_SUB > (curdate() - 604800)
ORDER BY `views` DESC
LIMIT 10
```