# To make report of how many products sold where entry date is in timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product table with product_id and entry_date field (which is varchar and have timestamp value by time() function in php). I want to get result of how many products have been uploaded per week. Please tell me the SQL so that I can get the result of how many products have been uploaded per week.

I also have user_id field.I also need how many products have been uploaded per week per user.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Assuming you know how to do a query, find out what the timestamps are you look for, and perform a `select` with a `where` that asks your entry-date to be between the 2 timestamps you just calculated. Then use `count()`

Answer (score 1):

possible duplicate: [Show most viewed entries that have been added in the last 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145237/show-most-viewed-entries-that-have-been-added-in-the-last-7-days)

try something like this:

```
SELECT data-you-want-to-retrieve
FROM `Your-Table`
WHERE entry_date > (curdate() - 604800)
```

So it sees that the entry date is larger than the date 7 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(entry_date), '_', WEEKOFYEAR(entry_date)) AS week, COUNT(*) Count, user_id
FROM `tbl_products` 
GROUP BY week, product_id, user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Count of product uploads per week:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(YEAR(entry_date), '_', WEEKOFYEAR(entry_date)) AS week, 
         COUNT(1) AS prodcnt
FROM     products
GROUP BY week
```

Count of products per week for a particular user:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(YEAR(entry_date), '_', WEEKOFYEAR(entry_date)) AS week, 
         COUNT(1) AS prodcnt
FROM     products
WHERE    user_id = <userid here>
GROUP BY week
```

You'll get results grouped by something like `2012_48`, where `48` is the week of the year (goes from 1-53).